# TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined and issue 2 is TypeError: Cannot read property 'downgradeElements' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, mern

I have successfully integrate react in express project but when i am calling "react-mdl" library it's showing 2 errors

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'downgradeElements' of undefined
```

In my app.js file i am doing:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Layout, Header, Navigation, Content } from 'react-mdl';
import Main from './components/main';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-big-content">
          <Layout>
              <Header>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="logo"><a href="/"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/truebase/static/truebase_logo.png" /></a></div>
                        <Navigation>
                            <a href="/">About</a>
                            <a href="https://www.trueprotocol.com">Protocol</a>
                        </Navigation>
                        <div className="login_buttons">
                            <Navigation>
                                <a href="/login">Login</a>
                                <a href="/signup" className="signs">Sign Up</a>
                            </Navigation>
                        </div>
                        <div className="right_search">
                            <form><i className="fa fa-search"></i>
                            <input type="text" className="key_input" placeholder="Search for Companies or People" />
                                <div className="sarch_rslt">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
                                            <h5>Pretend Co</h5>
                                            <p>San Francisco, Ca, USA</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
                                            <h5>Pretend Co</h5>
                                            <p>San Francisco, Ca, USA</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
                                            <h5>Pretend Co</h5>
                                            <p>San Francisco, Ca, USA</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
                                            <h5>Pretend Co</h5>
                                            <p>San Francisco, Ca, USA</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

              </Header>
          </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i am using layout, header, navigation and content from react-mdl library.
for more clarification of issue, when i comment the react-mdl library and stop using its components, error gone away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this issue while using react-mdl.
Adding below lines to `src/index.js` should solve the problem:

```
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';   
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you descript this problem in detail？This problem can be caused by many reasons.Besides,the react-mdl library is now deprecated, you can try Material Design Components instead.

Comment: hi there, thanks for your contribution. For your clarity i have edited my question with code and described in detail about the issue. kindly please check it again and let me know how to resolve it, if you know about

Comment: Add this to your file "import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js';".I think this will work.

Comment: I think you should read the description about the react-mdl on the Github.Because the Layout in react-mdl  doesn't work well on react,so you have to add this.